# Microsoft Cognitive auth token expiration

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

TL;DR
What's the expiration time of a Microsoft Cognitive Services auth token?

we're migrating our translator service calls from Bing to Microsoft Cognitive Services, which requires using a different auth key.

The old auth key had an "expires_in" field which set the expiration time for the token, however there isn't such a field in the new auth token and I can't find any documentation stating when it expires.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the few properties that still use the two-stage auth (Speech, for example) the tokens expire in 10 minutes ([doc](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#authenticate-the-api-call)).

For Translator, you should simply supply API key as the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header value ([doc](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html)).

Comment: Earlier there was a free subscription for Bing upto 20 lac characters. Is there any other way of free trial now? with limitation on characters?